# Running features cucumber in parallel in different browser using selenium testNG

Tags: testng, maven-plugin, selenium-grid, cucumber-jvm, parallel-testing

How can i run cucumber features using testNG and selenium or cucumber-JVM
i'm new in this but after my researsh i think that cucumber jvm doesn't work in paralell for me i added also the surefire plugin

now i try to test with TESTNG
my testNg.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="run test in parallel Suite" parallel="tests" verbose="1" configfailurepolicy="continue" thread-count="2">

  <listeners>

        <listener classname="com.driver.LocalWebDriverListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Tests in FF">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.runner.RunnerTestInFirefox" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Tests in Chrome" >
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome" />    
 <classes>
            <class name="com.runner.RunnerTestInChrome"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

and i create 2  class runner one for chrome and the other for firefox:

```
package com.runner;

    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
    import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
             features = {"/features"},
             glue={"stepsdefinition"})
    public class RunnerTestInChrome extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    }
```

when i run my test the browser chrome is open and closed but i don't why it didn't take the url and the steps in the feature!

Answer (score 0):

Afaik Cucumber does not support parallel execution, You might need to use an additional plugin or need to use [gherkin with qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html).
qaf is built upon TestNG for functional test automation, providing browser management, resource management, data-driven capability, detailed reports with screenshot and command-log...

When using gherkin with qaf, your configuration file may look like:

```
<suite name="run test in parallel Suite" parallel="tests" verbose="1" configfailurepolicy="continue" thread-count="2">
      <test name="Tests in FF">
            <parameter name="driver.name" value="firefoxDriver" />           
            <classes>
                  <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
            </classes>
      </test>
      <test name="Tests in Chrome">
            <parameter name="driver.name" value="chromeDriver"/>                      
            <classes>
                  <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
            </classes>
      </test>
</suite>
```

NOTE: If you want to run scenarios in parallel set `parallel="methods"` and `thread-count` accordingly.

You can start by walk-through [step by step tutorial](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki)