# Can we pass multiple browser names to execute parallelly through command line in Selenium Cucumber Maven framework

Tags: maven, cucumber-jvm, junit-runner, selenium3

Iam using **Selenium Cucumber Maven** framework with **Junit**. I need to run the feature file in different **browsers in parallel**(at the same time). 
Does this work if we pass browsernames like this ? 
     ***mvn test "-Dbrowser=chrome" , "-Dbrowser=firefox"*** through command line ? 
If not please help me with a solution.
I have been asking this doubt for 2 weeks and Iam not getting any reply. It would be really great if you guys help me with a solution. Thanks in advance .

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49741370/2458858) post and [this github](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) project:

Basically, you can use gherkin with qaf to do something like this:

```
<suite name="run test in parallel Suite" parallel="tests" verbose="1" configfailurepolicy="continue" thread-count="2">
      <test name="Tests in FF">
            <parameter name="driver.name" value="firefoxDriver" />           
            <classes>
                  <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
            </classes>
      </test>
      <test name="Tests in Chrome">
            <parameter name="driver.name" value="chromeDriver"/>                      
            <classes>
                  <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
            </classes>
      </test>
</suite>
```

**Community NOTE :** Since the referenced SO post does not have an accepted or upvoted answer, I could not mark this as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But actually I am using Cucumber-Junit TestRunner file. gherkin with qaf is for TestNG .right ?
Can I get a perfect solution with Selenium-Cucumber maven with Junit ?